# How to get historical swap data from different exchanges using web3js

Tags: ethereum, web3js, uniswap

[This is what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hJXaQ.jpg)

The `web3.eth.getTransaction()` doesn't provide the data I am looking for. I want to get historical data of a swap from token to the token and the amount.

Thanks for the help in advance.

Answer (score -1):

The data can be achieved through the `web3.eth.getTransactionRecipt()` function and query to log array.

Comment: Please, as per the rules, use the comments if you don't have to post code.

Comment: sure i am new here

Comment: Of course, now you are aware of it ;-)